# What is the difference between these two Redux reducer cases?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I saw someone write this code for a reducer:

```
export default function reducer(state, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            Object.assign({}, state, {
                todos: [{
                    text: action.text,
                    completed: false,
                }, ...state.todos]
            })
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Why not just do this?

```
case 'ADD_TODO':
   return [{text: action.txt, completed: false}, ...state.todos]
```

What's the difference?

Comment: `Object.assign` is not "pretty new". It's actually "pretty old" now. It's the browsers you are targeting which are "very old".

Answer (score 0):

In Redux, there's a concept of [Splitting Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html#splitting-reducers) which is used for better organization when it comes to deducing the new state. When you split up a reducer into multiple different reducers, then combine them with [`combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html), you essentially give each reducer a *slice of state* corresponding to the respective state it manages. For example, I could create a `todo` reducer to only every manage todos and only be aware of the todos inside state, and nothing else.

In the first snippet you've posted, the reducer is a 'master' reducer of sorts. The reducer function in that example is the reducer that handles *everything in state*, not just todos, and is aware of everything in state. That's why you need this code:

```
Object.assign({}, state, {
    todos: [{
        text: action.text,
        completed: false,
    }, ...state.todos]
})
```

This creates a copy of `state` to prevent mutation (via `Object.assign`), then updates the `todos` property of the cloned `state` with a new todo. In this 'master' reducer, the reducer is managing *all state* and thus must clone state and update the `todo` property.

In the second example, it would *not* work in this same reducer. That's because you're returning just an array as the new state. That would mean, whenever you added a todo, `state` would just become an array. Not good! Your second snippet would only work if you *split the master reducer* into more than one, and you had a separate reducer managing only todos. That means, that todo reducer would only get its respective 'slice of state'. It would only be aware of the `todos` property inside state, and nothing else in state:

```
export default function todos(state, action) { //This reducer is only aware of todos in state, nothing else.
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [{text: action.txt, completed: false}, ...state.todos] //This will modify only the `todos` property of state, not the whole state
  }
}
```

And in your master reducer file:

```
import todos from './your/todo/reducer/file';

combineReducers({
  todos
});
```

Here, `todos`'s `state` argument will only ever receive the `todos` property in state, it's slice. Nothing else. The first snippet would have received the whole entire state object as the `state` argument.

Comment: Edited the question, how about now?

Comment: @MadelineRies I added an in-depth explanation, hope it helps.